Twin sister pretends to be the other twin to get into her man's bed
Released probably in the 90s (or early 00s), this action melodrama features twin sisters in their 20s. Both wear high, medium length ponytails, and their hair looks red or orange dyed IIRC.
One of the sisters is in a relationship with a man.
In one scene, when this sister is away from the man, the other twin crawls into the man's bed pretending to be her sister / his girlfriend, and, hidden under the blanket i.e. without showing her face, does him a blow job. He thinks it's his girlfriend. Only after she finishes she shows her face and he realizes that she isn't, which puts him into distress and causes an altercation.
Does that sound familiar?

@user182601 It certainly wasn't a porno if that's what you mean. Just a regular melodrama with a few erotic scenes. Saw it on TV.

I'm at a loss why people would be voting to close this as lacking detail. I count at least nine relevant pieces of information that can be used to identify it. (1990s/action melodrama/movie/twin sisters/characters in their 20s/orange hair/one in an relationship/twin tricks man in bed/man is upset)

@user182601 Somehow that didn't prevent recognising and identifying the movie.

@user182601 - Her hair is certainly dyed orange, and she has a high ponytail earlier in the film. He doesn't throw her out of bed after the sexual encounter, but he does look freaked out. The fact that they're not twins is absolutely true, but they do look semi-identical which is a major point of the film.

@user182601 - More's the point, if OP remembered every detail 100% accurately they wouldn't need us to help them identify-this-movie.

@user182601 - the details you list, each and every one is almost exactly perfect.  eg, not "twin sisters" but "lookalikes" etc.  This is EXACTLY why you ask a question on here.

This is Single White Female (1992).
The two women aren't twins, but they do look increasingly alike as the roommate starts to intentionally copy the other one's look and style.



There's a scene where the roommate gets into bed with the boyfriend and sexually assaults him under the pretence of being her landlady.




Another perfect answer. Not to nitpick, but I think "... sexually assaults" is a bit confusing. (Or, God help us, "inappropriate" or something - a bit diminutive to actual sexual assault, I suppose.) She "tricks him in to having a fantastic time". (Or whatever is the best way to describe the situation.)

@Fattie - Rape by deception (otherwise known as 'Sexual Assault by Fraud') is a recognised crime in most states, including New York.

After re-watching the scene, it is clear now that she actually revealed to him who she was before performing the oral job. But he was too slow / hesitant / already turned on to stop it.

@Valorum don't blame me if you get "cancelled" or such  You know what I actually just glanced at it and, as GDrake says, it has nothing at all to do with that.  (Also purely FYI I'm not sure if you know I'm not American, so "New York" is just a place with incredibly bad food and bars - although i do live in the states currently!)

@Greendrake quite true !

@Greendrake - I think you've misunderstood the scene. He was firmly under the impression that it was Allie when the encounter started. He was also asleep.; https://imsdb.com/scripts/Single-White-Female.html he only realises towards the end that it's not her
